# Upgrading to php8 for a really old site but can't get <script language="php"> to be recognized

Tags: php

I have an old site where a lot of the pages used  for the php code, but I have found that php8 does not appear to recognize that by default, can that still be enabled? I was not able to find anything through google. Is that even possible now?

Comment: Can't you just do a find-and-replace and change them all to standard php opening blocks. I have to say I've been doing things in php for 15 years or more and never come across such a tag

Comment: The old tags have been removed after [this proposal](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_alternative_php_tags). Note that there's a porting script on that page. However, and this is a serious warning, much more has changed in PHP, over the last nine years, than just a tag, and there's no porting script for that.

Comment: I was going to, but the problem is the </script> that also covers some javascript.
I guess I will just have to change it all, at least I can find all the files that have it.

That tag was back from when I was using PHP 3